# Cassandra Nodes are active(exited)?

Tags: cassandra

Im working on a Cassandra Cluster with 5 Nodes. I uploaded some data to the Cluster and everything was ok but now i have the problem that the nodes go down, after 5 sec from their restart changes their status from active(running) to active(exited). 
did someone have the idea how to reset the Cluster or the Nodes or any other solution. thanks in advance

Comment: please provide logs - otherwise it's impossible to answer to your question.

Comment: in the system.log is erverything ok. i didn't find any errors. i uninstalled Cassandra and i did all the work another time but i get the same Failure now. All Nodes are active(exited).

Comment: there is a  warning:
1.WARN  [Service Thread] 2018-07-08 03:35:53,608 GCInspector.java:282 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 5415ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1677877304 -> 1679818752; Par Eden Space: 335544320 -> 45494704; Par Survivor Space: 41943040 -> 0
I asked my advisor in the thesis, he means it could be, because of the huge number of writes.